# An error combining DO and IF in Fortran

Tags: fortran

This is a part of code that I am writing in Visual FORTRAN 6.6A:

```
  .
  .
  .
   DO 24 I=1,80
24 IF ((NODNUM(1) .EQ. I) .AND. (CAUCHY(3,2) .LT. CTI(I+12))) THEN
      ARRAY(1)=C1*0.99
      END IF
  .
  .
  .
```

and this error occurs when I compile it:

> *--------------------Configuration: ovl30u_moon1 - Win32 Debug--------------------
>   Compiling Fortran...
>   C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\ovl30u_moon1.f
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\ovl30u_moon1.f(567) : Error: This is not a valid termination statement for a DO construct.
>
> 24 IF ((NODNUM(1) .EQ. I) .AND. (CAUCHY(3,2) .LT. CTI(I+12))) THEN
>   ---^
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser\Desktop\ovl30u_moon1.f(569) : Error: An ENDIF occurred without a corresponding IF THEN or ELSE statement.
>       END IF
>   -----------^
>
> Error executing df.exe.
>   ovl30u_moon1.obj - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)*

I also tried this but error exists yet:

```
   DO 24 I=1,80
24 IF ((NODNUM(1) .EQ. I) .AND. (CAUCHY(3,2) .LT. CTI(I+12))) THEN
      ARRAY(1)=C1*0.99
      END IF
   END DO
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I've attempted to improve the formatting of the compiler output - but I've had to guess a bit.  If it isn't quite right, my apologies but please correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The termination of a do loop using a label is not valid the way you specify it. For FORTRAN 77 use:

```
   DO 24 I=1,80
      IF ((NODNUM(1) .EQ. I) .AND. (CAUCHY(3,2) .LT. CTI(I+12))) THEN
          ARRAY(1)=C1*0.99
      END IF
24 CONTINUE
```

In Fortran 90+ you could simply leave out the label:

```
   DO I=1,80
      IF ((NODNUM(1) .EQ. I) .AND. (CAUCHY(3,2) .LT. CTI(I+12))) THEN
          ARRAY(1)=C1*0.99
      END IF
   END DO
```

Or, if you depend on the label, you could use

```
   label: DO I=1,80
      IF ((NODNUM(1) .EQ. I) .AND. (CAUCHY(3,2) .LT. CTI(I+12))) THEN
          ARRAY(1)=C1*0.99
      END IF
   END DO label
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Alexander Vogt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28583844/) there is another way to restate your particular case.

While it is not allowed to use an `if` construct as the termination of the non-block (labelled) `do` it is possible to use an `if` statement:

```
   DO 24 I=1,80
24 IF ((NODNUM(1) .EQ. I) .AND. (CAUCHY(3,2) .LT. CTI(I+12))) ARRAY(1)=C1*0.99
```

You can, but you really shouldn't: use the block construct as in the other anwer.

For more detail, see Fortran 2008 8.1.6.3 and R214.

Comment: Just for info - the current draft of [F201X](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/15/15-007.pdf) deletes this as an option, so perhaps that should be "You can, but you really, really, really shoudn't..."

Comment: I first thought you meant an if statement as an action termination, but it appears you mean the whole nonblock do construct is deleted (in the draft).